# Coroutine isnt canceled when swap to another activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I want the coroutine to be canceled when it switces to other activity. even if I switch to other activity in the code below, it continues to log.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while(true) {
            delay(5000)
            Log.i(TAG, "From lifecyclescope")
        }
    }
}
```

I solved the above problem easily with `viewLifecycleOwner` in fragment. When it go to the other fragment, it stops giving logs. How can I do this in activity?

Comment: Your lifecycle scoped coroutine will be cancelled only if activity will be destroyed. It may not happen on switching to another activity. Can you log activity "onDestroyed" callback to check if it actually happens?

Comment: If it’s appropriate to your use case, you can wrap the code that’s inside your coroutine with `repeatOnLifecycle` otherwise, store your Job in a property and cancel it manually when you call `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in onPause

```
var job: Job? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
    job = lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        while(true) {
            delay(5000)
            Log.i("TAG", "From lifecyclescope")
        }
    }
```

in onPause

```
override fun onPause() {
        job?.cancel()
        super.onPause()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to achieve a similar behavior by using `repeatOnLifecycle`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            while(true) {
                delay(5000)
                Log.i(TAG, "From lifecyclescope")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference is that the coroutine will be canceled when the activity reaches the stopped state. This happens when the activity is no longer visible, such as when another activity appears or when the user minimizes your application.